# Loop to get sum of factorial / exponent

Tags: c, function, sum, nested-loops, factorial

Hello I wrote a loop to get the sum of the factorial of given value n divided by n with increasing exponent. To describe it better it looks like this:

[image]

But for some reason my loop is always returning the value 1 whenever I input a number.
Here's my loop:

```
int nVal, i, j, k, nProduct = 1, nSum = 0, nFactorial = 1;
float fResult;

for (i = 1; i <= nVal; i++)
{
    for (j = 1; j <= nVal; j++)
    {
        nFactorial *= j;
        nSum += nFactorial;
    }
    for (k = 1; k <= nVal; k++)
    {   
        nProduct *= k;
    }
    fResult += (nSum * 1.0) / (nProduct * 1.0);
}
```

Any fixes I can try?

Comment: Is that really your complete code? `nVal` is not set to any value. Please provide a [complete minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What does `nSum` represent?

Comment: Curious OP's `(nSum * 1.0) / (nProduct * 1.0);` uses `double` math to do the division, yet then added the `double` quotient to a `float`.  To perform `float` division, use `f`: `1.0f * nSum / nProduct;` - or better yet, use `double fResult;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How big will `n` get? This can dictate what the type for `nProduct` and `nFactorial` should be (e.g. `int` or `long long` or `__int128` or `double`).

The nested/inner loops are wrong. You only want/need the `for` loop for `i`.

And you'll [possibly/probably] overflow/underflow if you wait to calculate the ratio. So, do this at each iteration.

Your factorial calculation line was okay. But, the `nProduct` calculation was incorrect. The multiplier has to be `n` [and not `j`].

You don't initialize `fResult`, so it starts with a random value (i.e. undefined behavior). This would be flagged if you compiled with `-Wall` [and `-O2`] to enable warnings.

Remember that:

```
k! = (k - 1)! * k
```

And, that:

```
n**k = n**(k - 1) * n
```

So, we can build up `nFactorial` subterms and `nProduct` subterms iteratively, in a single loop.

Here's what I think your code should be like:

```
// pick _one_ of these:
#if 0
typedef int acc_t;
#endif
#if 0
typedef long long acc_t;
#endif
#if 0
typedef __int128 acc_t;
#endif
#if 1
typedef double acc_t;
#endif

double
calc1(int nVal)
{
    int i;
    acc_t nProduct = 1;
    acc_t nFactorial = 1;
    double ratio;
    double fResult = 0;

    for (i = 1;  i <= nVal;  ++i) {
        nFactorial *= i;
        nProduct *= nVal;

        ratio = (double) nFactorial / (double) nProduct;
        fResult += ratio;
    }

    return fResult;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

OP's code is incorrect in the numerator and denominator calculation.  Also, the integer math readily overflows.

To better handle large `n`, form each term based on the prior term with floating point math.

```
double sum_fact_expo(int n) {
  double sum = 0.0;
  double ratio = 1.0;
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    ratio *= 1.0*i/n;
    sum += ratio;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int nVal, i, j, k, nProduct = 1, nFactorial = 1;
  float fResult = 0;

  scanf("%d", &nVal);

  for (i = 1; i <= nVal; i++)
  {
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {   
      //calculate 1! 2! 3! ... n!
      //actually calculate i!
      nFactorial *= j;
    }   
    for (k = 1; k <= i; k++)
    {   
      //calculate n^1 n^2 n^3 ... n^n
      //actually calculate n^i
      nProduct *= nVal;
    }   
    fResult += (nFactorial * 1.0) / (nProduct * 1.0);
    nProduct = 1;
    nFactorial = 1;
  }

  printf("%f\n", fResult);
  return 0;
}
```